# In photoshop CS6, what are the main differences between the stamp tool and content-aware tool?

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing

When using the content-aware and stamp tools in Photoshop, it appears to be using a similar method for determining the new fill for the specified area. What are the main differences between the two tools (i.e. different algorithms, effect possibility, uses, etc.), and are the instances where one will always be better to use than the other?

Comment: Which content-aware tool? Photoshop CS6 has several, including content-aware fill, content-aware spot healing, content-aware patch and content-aware move (in addition to content-aware scaling, which is not germaine to the question). Each of them work somewhat differently.

Answer (score 2):

The clone stamp tool gives you direct control over what you are filling with.  The content-aware uses an algorithm to pick what to fill with.  Content-aware is faster when it works, but clone stamp gives you more fine grained control and can handle more difficult situations.